# Fix extent of R rasters (grid_density output) to match

Tags: raster, r, alignment

I have two rasters that are the result of the `grid_density()` function from the liDR package. With those rasters I want to compare point distribution of subsets of a LAS file.
My problem is, that I get **rasters with different extent** (since `grid_density()` aligns the extent of the output raster exactly to the point cloud. If the point cloud is filtered, points at the edges might be missing and the output raster shrinks a bit.

Often, this is only on one side and by a few rows or colums. Since the rasters are generally in the same resolution, I'd rather avoid a `resample()`, since it is slow and requires interpolation that shouldn't be needed in most cases.

[image: different extents]

A code example:

```
# create reference raster with all points
dgrid_ref = grid_density(las, 2)

# filter las pointcloud and create raster
las_c1 = filter_poi(lasp, Z>=0, Z<5)
dgrid_c1  = grid_density(las_c1, 2)

las_c2 = filter_poi(lasp, Z>=5, Z<9)
dgrid_c2  = grid_density(las_c2, 2)
```

I tried simply overriding the extent with `dgrid_c1 = setExtent(dgrid_c1, dgrid_ref, keepres = TRUE)`, however that leaves me with a raster that contains only NAs.

I also thought to create an "empty" raster of the reference extent and then "inserting" the subset raster, but couldn't find a way to "paste" a raster into another.

Is there an option to use a "snap raster" for `grid_density()` that determines the output?
Or is there a better option than to `resample()`? Like overwriting the extent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found out [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/418332/change-extent-of-lidr-las-object-for-raster-generation-with-grid-metrics-grid-c/418339#418339), there is the option to pass a `RasterLayer` to the grid_density function (`res = raster(xy)`), which will then be used as the Layout of the output (e.g. see [doc on `grid_canopy`](https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/man/grid_canopy.html)).

Using the same RasterLayer Layout on both

```
# create reference raster with all points
dgrid_ref = grid_density(las, 2)

# filter las pointcloud and create raster
las_c1 = filter_poi(lasp, Z>=0, Z<5)
dgrid_c1  = grid_density(las_c1, res=dgrid_ref)

las_c2 = filter_poi(lasp, Z>=5, Z<9)
dgrid_c2  = grid_density(las_c2, res=dgrid_ref)
```

will then use `dgrid_ref` for extent and resolution. `extend` won't be needed then.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `extend` here. Let's make a sample...

Full-world raster:

```
> rfull = raster()
> rfull[]=1:ncell(rfull)
```

And extract a smaller raster with the same resolution and origin, so the cells overlap perfectly:

```
> e = extent(-20,10,-30,0)
> rpart = crop(rfull, e)
> rpart[] = 1:ncell(rpart)
```

Now we have these two rasters:

```
> extent(rfull)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -180 
xmax       : 180 
ymin       : -90 
ymax       : 90 
> extent(rpart)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -20 
xmax       : 10 
ymin       : -30 
ymax       : 0
```

We want to extend the small raster to the extent of the large one, by padding with NA:

```
> 
> rpack = extend(rpart, rfull)
> 
> extent(rpack)
class      : Extent 
xmin       : -180 
xmax       : 180 
ymin       : -90 
ymax       : 90
```

Plotting `plot(rpack)` gives this:

[image]

where you can see the extent is padded out to the extent of the full world raster.

(Note that using `extend` on a big raster to the extent of a small raster results in an unchanged raster.)

Comment: cool, I didn't know about this function. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Me neither. But I thought "hmmm there must be a function to do this in the raster package...", typed `ls(package:raster)` and guessed...